# AzureAD not accepting my HTTP URL from my NodeJS OAuth2

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a NodeJS Application utilizing OAuth2. I do not have SSL. I am trying to authenticate using Single Sign-on with Microsoft. While it works on localhost, it doesn't work with network's IP. Any idea?

On MS Website it says I should be able to:

> The Azure AD application model today supports both HTTP and HTTPS
>   schemes for apps that sign in Microsoft work or school accounts in any
>   organization's Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant. That is
>   signInAudience field in the application manifest is set to either
>   AzureADMyOrg or AzureADMultipleOrgs. For the apps that sign in
>   Personal Microsoft accounts and work and school accounts (that is
>   signInAudience set to AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount) only HTTPS
>   scheme is allowed.

I have the Manifest set to AzureADMultipleOrgs

[image: Azure]

Answer (score 1):

The redirect URL should still be using [`HTTPS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#restrictions-on-redirect-urls),

In general, they do not support transmitting tokens over unsecured channels. Currently, apps that are registered in the Application Registration Portal are restricted to a limited set of redirect URI values. The redirect URI for web apps and services must begin with the scheme https.

Comment: So ideally I will have to make my NodeJS an HTTPS?

Comment: yeah you need to